# When exactly was The Man Trap first aired?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I know it happened on September 8, 1966, but I would like to find out the exact UTC time. According to Wikipedia,

> The first regular episode of Star Trek, The Man Trap,[23] aired on Thursday, September 8, 1966 from 8:30–9:30 as part of an NBC "sneak preview" block.

Unfortunately, this information is insufficient, since I don't know the time zone.

**Edit:** As DJClayworth kindly pointed out, Canadian CTV network aired it two days earlier, on September 6. I am only interested in NBC broadcast, since it is a bit more well-known.

Comment: Most US broadcasting companies base (and did base) off of Eastern time.  I think.

Comment: [The actual first airing of The Man Trap was on the Canadian CTV network, September 6th 1966.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)

Comment: Mostly we used the term GMT back then, UTC wasn't really common, or fully adopted in 1966.

Comment: 'The only one everybody knows about'? That's only true of your tiny little country south of the 49th parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual first ever showing of Star Trek was [on the Canadian CTV network, September 6th 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series).

If you mean the first American showing, that was on [September 8th 1966 starting at 8.30pm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series#Season_1_.281966.E2.80.9367.29). Times like this are invariably in Eastern Daylight time, so that would have been 12.30am on September 9th UTC.

Answer (score 2):

The NBC premiere was at 8:30 **Eastern Time** on September 8th. According to most sources, such as  [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=HrGQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT190&lpg=PT190&dq=nielsen+rating+%E2%80%9Ceastern+time%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=Fn-0RKD5sJ&sig=ZiBFirj4wtZeMNr2M_DxRG4Sf3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT-9eI-v3OAhXD4IMKHRL4BPk4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=nielsen%20rating%20%E2%80%9Ceastern%20time%E2%80%9D&f=false), Nielsen uses Eastern Time for their ratings.

Further, the *New York Times* wrote on September 16, 1966:

> Star Trek, which NBC is presenting at 8:30 p.m. on Thursdays this
>   season, makes it clear that life in space will probably be more
>   traumatic than on Earth.

Since the *Times* is on Eastern Time, presumably 8:30 is when the show aired locally.

The actual premiere was at 7:30 P.M., September 6 in Canada, as [indicated](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=Fr8DH2VBP9sC&dat=19660906&printsec=frontpage&hl=en) in the September 6 *Montreal Gazette.*

[image]

Given that Montreal is on Eastern Time, I  would assume this is 7:30 P.M. Eastern Time. However, Canada instituted [delays](http://www.broadcasting-history.ca/index3.html?url=http%3A//www.broadcasting-history.ca/networks/Calgary_Delay_Centres.html) in the 1960s, in order to allow people to watch shows at the same time. If this affected *Star Trek*, its actual premiere could have been two hours earlier.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Canada instituted delays starting in 1966. Initially it appears they were only for CTV programs, with affiliates not coming until several years later. So in brief - yes.